# NoMethodError in Posts#index, undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. I'm currently on section 5.8 which should list all the posts in my blog at localhost:3000/posts, but am instead getting a message:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#index
Showing /Users/sw/Code/blog/app/views/posts/index.html.erb where line #9 raised:
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #9):

    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= post.title %></td>
            <td><%= post.text %></td>
```

Here's my posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @post = Post.all
end

def new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end
```

end

And here's my index.html.erb:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
</tr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= post.title %></td>
        <td><%= post.text %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

I've been searching all over and haven't been able to find an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping through a variable `@posts`, but in your index you are assigning a variable `@post`.

Thus, in your `posts_controller.rb` replace

```
def index
  @post = Post.all
end
```

with

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```